org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException for custom repository
I'm trying to write a generic custom repository.
Trying to create Spring Data Query for Custom Repository. I couldn't find the problem. How can I solve it?
Spring Boot version: 3.2.2
Error
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.example.repository.MakerCheckerRepository.merge(com.example.entity.MakerCheckerEntity); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean com.example.repository.MakerCheckerRepository.merges(com.example.makerchecker.entity.MakerCheckerEntity); No property 'merge' found for type 'BankType'

Custom Repository
import java.io.Serializable;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MakerCheckerRepository<E extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> {

    boolean persist(E entity);

    boolean merge(E entity);

}

Custom Repository Impl
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MakerCheckerRepositoryImpl<E extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements MakerCheckerRepository<E, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    public void persist(E entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void merge(E entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}

Repository class
@Repository
public interface BankTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<BankType, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BankType>, BankTypeRepositoryCustom, MakerCheckerRepository<BankType, Long> {
}

Entity
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANK_TYPE")
public class BankType extends MakerCheckerEntity implements Serializable {
     .....
}


Please Provide BankType entity . It help us to understand the properly.

May be Spring Data treat MakerCheckerRepository as repository itself.
When we create query by writing a method with Spring data JPA then Spring Data expect name of that method must contain the property name in The entity.
for Example -
public interface ReportQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<ReportQuery, Long> {
    List<ReportQuery> findAllByReportType(ReportType type);
} 

Here Spring Data Expect That ReportQuery Entity Must have a property name ReportType. if there are no property name ReportType the it ecounter the error No property 'merge' found for type 'BankType'
Lets Come to the Your Problem :
At first, in  MakerCheckerRepository use two method persist and merge, this two are basically two operation like save and update.
Spring data convert any method in the interface to a query based on naming convention that match with particular entity.

You Can use @NoRepositoryBean on MakerCheckerRepository so that spring data don not treat MakerCheckerRepository as repository itself.


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MakerCheckerRepository<E extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> {

    boolean persist(E entity);

    boolean merge(E entity);

} 

and You can define repository path
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="YOUR REOSITORY PACKEG")

Note : If you share your BankType Entity ,i will more clear.

First of all, thank you for your answer. I tried what you said, but the same problem persists.

can you please provide BankType Entity ?

How can you @Override a boolean method by a void directly?
